# Reading multiple XML files in a specific folder - Python

Tags: python, xml, file, directory

I need a little help from you guys.

Im new to programming, so dont expect much from my code.

Here is the thing, i need to parse a bunch of XML files in a folder and write it on a .xls or a .csv. Until now i've made it to parse the xml and write it to a .txt, but the file that ive use it is located in the same folder that the program is.

Here is the code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

from datetime import *

ano = int(input("Year: "))

mes = int(input("Month: "))

dia = int(input("Day: "))

dt_obj = datetime(ano, mes, dia)

date_str = dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#Extracting the information from the XML nodes

xmldoc = minidom.parse("NAME OF THE FILE.XML")

NFe = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("NFe")[0]

infNFe = NFe.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0]

ide = infNFe.getElementsByTagName("ide")[0]

nNF = ide.getElementsByTagName("nNF")[0].firstChild.data

dEmi = ide.getElementsByTagName("dEmi")[0].firstChild.data

serie = ide.getElementsByTagName("serie")[0].firstChild.data

emit = infNFe.getElementsByTagName("emit")[0]

cnpj = emit.getElementsByTagName("CNPJ")[0].firstChild.data

nfeProc = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("nfeProc")[0]

chNFe = nfeProc.getElementsByTagName("chNFe")[0].firstChild.data


try:

    # This will create a new file or **overwrite an existing file**.

    f = open(date_str+".txt", "w")
    try:
        f.write("CNPJ: "+cnpj) # Write a string to a file
        f.writelines("\nNUMERO DA NOTA: "+nNF)
        f.write("\nDATA DE EMISSAO: "+dEmi)
        f.write("\nSERIE: "+serie)
        f.write("\nCHAVE ELETRONICA: "+chNFe)
    finally:
        f.close()
 except IOError:
    pass
```

I've succeed reading the XML, parsing it and write the information from the nodes that i needed.

What i need now is to read a folder with a bunch of them and writing on a .XLS

Anyone?

Comment: http://www.python-excel.org/ provides a list of tools for working with xls file.  Do you really need xls or will csv do?

Comment: have you found a solution? either mark an answer that helped you, or create your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the xml files are in a single folder, you can do something like:

```
import os
import sys

def select_files_in_folder(dir, ext):
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        if file.endswith('.%s' % ext):
            yield os.path.join(dir, file)

for file in select_files_in_folder(sys.argv[1], 'xml'):
    process_xml_file(file)
```

Or, if the files can be in subfolders, use:

```
def select_files_in_subfolders(dir, ext):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.%s' % ext):
                yield os.path.join(dir, file)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on for size.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from datetime import *

ano = int(input("Year: "))
mes = int(input("Month: "))
dia = int(input("Day: "))
dt_obj = datetime(ano, mes, dia)
date_str = dt_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#Extracting the information from the XML nodes

def get_files(d):
        return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d,f))]

def parse(files):
    for xml_file in files:
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(xml_file)
        NFe = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("NFe")[0]
        infNFe = NFe.getElementsByTagName("infNFe")[0]
        ide = infNFe.getElementsByTagName("ide")[0]
        nNF = ide.getElementsByTagName("nNF")[0].firstChild.data
        dEmi = ide.getElementsByTagName("dEmi")[0].firstChild.data
        serie = ide.getElementsByTagName("serie")[0].firstChild.data
        emit = infNFe.getElementsByTagName("emit")[0]
        cnpj = emit.getElementsByTagName("CNPJ")[0].firstChild.data
        # now whatever you want...

parse(get_files(DIRECTORY))
```

DIRECTORY being the location where the XML files are.

since this is only partial of your code, you will need to fill in the rest on your own. you have not provided exactly what you want to write, or the format you want to write it in....

something to help you write your CSV FILE:

```
# csv_lovation is a location os a *.csv file, and contents is a list of lists:
# ( [ ["row1 item1", "row1 item2", "row1 item3"], ["row2 item1", "row2 item2", "row2 item3"] ] )
def write_csv(csv_location, contents):
    with open(csv_location, "w") as file_writer:
        file_writer.write("Header,Items,Here\n") #if you have no need for a header, remove this line.
            for line in contents:
                file_writer.write("%s\n" % ",".join(line))
```